# Hover event on div element

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I create some div element on the fly. The opacity is 0.5. On hover I want to change the opacity using jquery but the program does not respond.

`<div id="main"></div>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
try {
    $.get(url, function (result) {
        $.each(result.data, function (i, rowElement) {
            $('#main').append(`<div class="divHover">
            <label class="playlist-name">${this.name}</label>
            <div class="playlistCon">
            <div class="playlist-all-btn">
                <button class="deletePL-btn"><img class="deletePL-img" src="IMG/delete.png"></button>
                <button class="editPL-btn"><img class="editPL-img" src="IMG/edit.png"></button>
                <button class="playPL-btn" id='${this.id}'><img class="playPL-img" src="IMG/play.png"></button>
            </div>
        </div>        
          </div>`);
        });
    });

} catch (err) {
    alert(err.toString());
}});




        $(".playlistCon").hover(function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.playlistCon').css("opacity", "1");
            $(this).parent().find('.playlist-all-btn').css("display", "block");
        },
            function () {
                $(this).parent().find('.playlistCon').css("opacity", "0.5");
                $(this).parent().find('.playlist-all-btn').css("display", "none");
            });
```

By the way, when I added the div element inside html file it worked.

```
<div id="main">
            <div class="divHover">
                    <label class="playlist-name">AAAAA</label>
                    <div class="playlistCon">
                        <div class="playlist-all-btn">
                            <button class="deletePL-btn"><img class="deletePL-img" src="IMG/delete.png"></button>
                            <button class="editPL-btn"><img class="editPL-img" src="IMG/edit.png"></button>
                            <button class="playPL-btn"><img class="playPL-img" src="IMG/play.png"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Classic. You're `.hover()` function is attaching the listener to the divs that are on the page _at that time_. It does not apply to divs that might exist in the future. You can use `delegation` (look it up), or, you can move the part of the code that attachs the hover to be _inside_ the $.get request. After the `.each` is done, all the divs are rendered, now attach the `.hover()` call to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It was great to get up in the morning and find out  the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're $.get call takes time to get the data and render the new HTML. But your other javascript still runs. So, when you're trying to attach event listeners, there are ZERO divs to attach to.

It does not apply to future divs. All future items need to have listeners added to them AFTER they are on the page. So below you can see how we wait for them to be appended to the page, *then* we add the listeners to them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        $.get(url, function(result) {
            $.each(result.data, function(i, rowElement) {
                $('#main').append(`
                <div class="divHover">
                    <label class="playlist-name">${this.name}</label>
                    <div class="playlistCon">
                        <div class="playlist-all-btn">
                            <button class="deletePL-btn"><img class="deletePL-img" src="IMG/delete.png"></button>
                            <button class="editPL-btn"><img class="editPL-img" src="IMG/edit.png"></button>
                            <button class="playPL-btn" id='${this.id}'><img class="playPL-img" src="IMG/play.png"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>        
              </div>
                `);
            });
            // .each is done, all html is rendered
            var number_divs =  $(".playlistCon").length; 
            console.log(`But now... there are ${number_divs} divs to listen for hover on!`);

            // NOW I can attach listeners to them
            $(".playlistCon").hover(function() {
                $(this).parent().find('.playlistCon').css("opacity", "1");
                $(this).parent().find('.playlist-all-btn').css("display", "block");
            },
            function() {
                $(this).parent().find('.playlistCon').css("opacity", "0.5");
                $(this).parent().find('.playlist-all-btn').css("display", "none");
            });
        });

    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.toString());
    }
});


var number_divs =  $(".playlistCon").length; 
console.log(`Right now there are ${number_divs} divs to listen for hover on.`);
```

Alternatively, you can attach a single listener to the parent div, and use `event delegation` to do things. This will apply to future html! [Read about Event Delegation here.](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It was great to get up in the morning and find out  the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because when you register the listener for the **hover** event, there is no element with class **playlistCon**. I will try moving this listener after you get the data. Also, you have to move the listener to class **divHover** since hover on an elmenent who have all their childs hiddens won't be triggered. Try next modifications:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    try
    {
        $.get(url, function (result)
        {
            // Append elements to main div.

            $.each(result.data, function (i, rowElement)
            {
                $('#main').append(
                `<div class="divHover">
                    <label class="playlist-name">${this.name}</label>
                    <div class="playlistCon">
                    <div class="playlist-all-btn">
                        <button class="deletePL-btn"><img class="deletePL-img" src="IMG/delete.png"></button>
                        <button class="editPL-btn"><img class="editPL-img" src="IMG/edit.png"></button>
                        <button class="playPL-btn" id='${this.id}'><img class="playPL-img" src="IMG/play.png"></button>
                    </div>
                    </div>        
                </div>`
                );
            });

            // Register listeners for elements with class "playlistCon".

            $(".divHover").hover(function ()
            {
                $(this).css("opacity", "1");
                $(this).find('.playlist-all-btn').css("display", "block");
            },
            function ()
            {
                $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
                $(this).find('.playlist-all-btn').css("display", "none");
            });
        });
     }
     catch (err)
     {
        alert(err.toString());
     }
});
```